# Python Dictionary accessing keys from duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {"student 1":22,"student 2":20,"student 3":22,"student 4":19}
search = int(input("Enter age :"))
```

using this age value print name of all the students from dict
if age is not present in dict show error message.

```
output:
Enter age: 22
student 1
student 3
```

> Enter age: 26 age is not found

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far?

Comment: Naming a variable `dict` is extremely bad because it overwrites the `dict` builtin.  I say this in all seriousness -- if you're taking a class in Python and one of the assignments does something like this, get out of that class if you can.  Any of the free tutorials online will be a better resource.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming your `dict` to `students` (because naming something `dict` is bad):

```
students = {"student 1":22,"student 2":20,"student 3":22,"student 4":19}
search = int(input("Enter age :"))
```

here's two lines of code to get the list of matching names and then print it in the desired format:

```
matches = [name for name, age in students.items() if age == search]
print("\n".join(matches) if matches else "age is not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output in the exact format you specified.

```
dict = {"student 1":22,"student 2":20,"student 3":22,"student 4":19} 

def findStudentsWithAge(age):
    result = []
    for key, val in dict.items():
        if val == age:
            result.append(key)

    return result

search = int(input("Enter age: "))

results = findStudentsWithAge(search)

if len(results) > 0: print(" ".join(results)) #space separated string
else: print("age is not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the best solution but worth giving a try.

```
dict1 = {"student 1":22,"student 2":20,"student 3":22,"student 4":19} 
search = int(input("Enter age :"))
count=0
for dicts in dict1:
    if dict1.get(dicts)==search:
        print(dicts)
        count+=1
        
if count==0:
    print("Students not found")
```

More better solution

```
dict1 = {"student 1":22,"student 2":20,"student 3":22,"student 4":19} 
search = int(input("Enter age :"))
count=[x for x in dict1 if dict1.get(x)==search]
if len(count)==0:
    print("Students not found")
else:
    print("Students found:\n",*count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this in order to get those values.

```
def get_students(dict, age):
    print(f"Entered age= {age}")
    present = False
    for student in dict:
        if dict[student] == age:
            present = True
            print(student)
    if present == False:
        print(f"Age {age} is not found")
```